# VBA Excel simple Error Handling

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have looked online as much as I could (except for the Microsoft support website, which is blocked at work for some reason). I am trying to simply skip an error. My code written here is simplified but should work the same way.

**What my code is supposed to do:**
One of my subs creates shapes in a loop and names them (btn_1, btn_2, etc). But before creating them, it calls a sub that tries to delete them so as not to create duplicates. This sub loops through (btn_1, btn_2, etc) and deletes the shapes using:

```
for i = 1 to (a certain number)
    Set shp = f_overview.Shapes("btn_" & i)
    shp.delete
next
```

Of course, it happens that the shape cannot be deleted because it simply does not exist. I have found that most of the time, the reccomended fix is to add (on error resume next) before setting the shape, as I get an error saying it does not exist. I have tried it inside the loop, before the loop, etc, like so:

```
for i = 1 to (a certain number)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = f_overview.Shapes("btn_" & i)
    shp.delete
next
```

As far as I understand it is supposed to loop right through if the shape doesn't exist, but I still get the same error whether or not I add the On error resume next! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: There is no error when the shapes do exist.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I have found that most of the time, the reccomended fix is to add (on error resume next) before setting the shape, as I get an error saying it does not exist.

## NO!

The recommended way to *handle* runtime errors is **not** to shove them under the carpet and continue execution as if nothing happened - which is exactly what `On Error Resume Next` does.

The simplest way to *avoid* runtime errors is to check for error conditions, and avoid executing code that results in 100% failure rate, like trying to run a method on an object reference that's `Nothing`:

```
For i = 1 To (a certain number)
    Set shp = f_overview.Shapes("btn_" & i)
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then shp.Delete
Next
```

---

In cases where you can't check for error conditions and *must* handle errors, the recommended way is to *handle* them:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    '...code...

CleanExit:
    'cleanup code here
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then 'subscript out of range
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume CleanExit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ on Proper Error Handling :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout yeah, except I didn't test it and now the more I think of it, the more I believe the assignment would throw an `index out of range` error, in which case [FreeMan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30489225/1188513) has a better solution.

Comment: That;s ok :) Edit your above code. My comment was the proper error handling that you showed t the bottom of the post. i did mention about that in my post as well :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout edited, ...without stealing from anyone's answer :)

Comment: Good tips, for someone new to error handling like me. The reason it was failing, though, was apparently because I had the wrong settings (see chosen answer).

Comment: No need to explicitly "Err.Clear" before the Resume Next. As for the MS Docs "The Err object's properties are reset to zero or zero-length strings ("") after an Exit Sub, Exit Function, Exit Property, or Resume Next statement within an error-handling routine. Using any form of the Resume statement outside of an error-handling routine will not reset the Err object's properties. The Clear method can be used to explicitly reset Err."

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing WRONG in using **OERN** (*On Error Resume Next*) provided you understand what you are doing and how it is going to affect your code.

In your case it is perfectly normal to use OERN

```
Dim shp As Shape

For i = 1 To (a certain number)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = f_overview.Shapes("btn_" & i)
    shp.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

At the same time ensure that you don't do something like

```
On Error Resume Next
<Your Entire Procedure>
On Error GoTo 0
```

This will suppress ALL errors. Use proper error handling as shown by Matt

**Edit**:

Here is another beautiful example on how to use **OERN** This function checks if a particular worksheet exists or not.

```
Function DoesWSExist(wsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesWSExist = True
End Function
```

If you wish you can also loop through all the sheets to check is the sheet exists or not!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The reason it was failing, though, was because I had the wrong settings (see chosen answer).

Comment: ++ but unfortunately most don't understand the implications of using OERN. I like that acronym btw. I'm keeping it.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of trying to blindly delete shapes and skipping errors, why not run through the list of known shapes and delete them. Then you don't have to worry about an `On Error Resume Next` which *often* ends up being abused.

```
Sub Test(TheSheet As Worksheet)

Dim Shp as Shape

For Each Shp in TheSheet.Shapes
  If left(Shp.Name, 4) = "btn_" Then
    Shp.Delete
  End if
Next

End Sub
```

If you want to delete all shapes, remove the `If` statement. If you want to delete a number of differently named shapes, modify the `If` statement appropriately.

Comment: AH excellent! This is the way I will choose to do it. Thank you for the fix. +1 for answer even though you don't explain how to use error handling :-)

Comment: You are correct on the lack of error handling detail - this loop doesn't require it, especially not in the way you were thinking. [Mat's Mug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30489275/2344413) does a fine job of covering error handling in general.

Comment: It's OK, [@FreeMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489035/vba-excel-simple-error-handling/30489225#comment90810913_30489225), 3 months after that, there was a random drive-by upvote! :)

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you have the wrong error trapping option set.  Within the VBA Editor, Select `Tools -> Options`.  In the window that opens, select the `General tab`, and pick the `Break on Unhandled Errors` radio button.  This should allow Excel to properly process the `On Error Resume Next` command.

I suspect that you have `Break on All Errors` selected.

Comment: Thanks! I kept trying the suggestions of the other answerers and all failed. This was why although they also provided valuable information!

Comment: @DavidGrand'Maison I agree that the error handling being done in the other answers is cleaner and better.  But your original code should have worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
On Error Resume Next

for i = 1 to (a certain number)
    Set shp = f_overview.Shapes("btn_" & i)
    if err<>0 then err.clear else shp.delete
next

on Error Goto 0
```