# Check sheet names to avoid duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, rename

I am working on a macro, a part of which takes input from the user asking what he/she would like to rename the sheet. It works fine, but I run into a runtime error if the name provided by the user is already being used by a different sheet. I understand why the error occurs but am not sure as to how I could warn the user and handle the error.

My code is as follows:-

```
'Change sheet name

Dim sheetname As String

sheetname = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Model Code (eg 2SV)", _
      Title:="Model Code", Default:="Model Code here")

wsCopyTo.Name = sheetname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this.

First, trap the error, check if there was an error, and advise, then put the error trapping back to what it was

```
Dim sheetname As String

sheetname = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Model Code (eg 2SV)", _
      Title:="Model Code", Default:="Model Code here")

On Error Resume next
Err.Clear 'ensure previously unhandled errors do not give a false positive on err.number
wsCopyTo.Name = sheetname
If Err.Number = ?? then 'go back and ask for another name
On Error Goto 0
```

Second, check all the current sheet names, and see if there is a match

```
Dim sheetname As String
Dim sh 'as Sheet

sheetname = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Model Code (eg 2SV)", _
      Title:="Model Code", Default:="Model Code here")

for each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     If lower(sh.name)=lower(sheetname) then
         'Goback and ask for another name
Next

wsCopyTo.Name = sheetname
```

Comment: Marked as correct because of clarity in what is being done and multiple ways to handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looping through the ones you have and compare their names with the one the user gave. If it matches, write a message saying that's used already. Exit the sub afterwards.

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = sheetname then
             msgbox "This name is already in use!"
             exit sub
        End if
Next
```

Comment: For proper error trapping, I do not suggest Err.Clear. See this guide I received a few weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489035/vba-excel-simple-error-handling It is the highest voted answer.

Comment: I think your comment is on the wrong answer, and the reason I use `err.clear` is that if there is a previously unhandled error on the stack, then that could cause the `err.number` check to fail, as the value only gets changed on an error, or when Err.Clear is executed

Comment: Just like a glove!

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a post about using Excel's native Rename Sheet dialog to do this. That way you get error-checking for duplicates, illegal characters and names that are too long. Here's a routine that adds a sheet and calls the dialog. If the user doesn't rename it, then the new sheet is deleted:

```
Sub PromptForNewSheetWithName()
Dim DefaultSheetName As String

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DefaultSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogWorkbookName).Show
If ActiveSheet.Name = DefaultSheetName Then
    MsgBox "You didn't name the new sheet." & vbCrLf & _
           "Processing cancelled", vbExclamation
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
End Sub
```

The whole post is at: http://yoursumbuddy.com/prompt-to-name-new-sheet/

Comment: This is very helpful. Is there a way I could modify what it says? I'd like the dialog box to say **"Enter Model Code (eg 2SV)"**.

Comment: Good question. Alas, no there's not, at least that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a Worksheet variable and Set it to what user has input (you might want to **Trim()** as well to remove leading and trailing spaces).

If it's Nothing then name is safe to use. If **Not Is Nothing** then it already exists.

```
Dim oWS As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname)

If oWS Is Nothing Then
    ' Safe to use the name
    Debug.Print """" & sheetname & """ is save to use."
    Err.Clear
    wsCopyTo.Name = sheetname
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot use """ & sheetname & """ as worksheet name."
        Err.Clear
    End If
Else
    Debug.Print """" & sheetname & """ exists already! Cannot use."
    ' worksheet with same name already!
    ' handle it here

End If
Set oWS = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
```

You could also put it into a loop until a unused sheetname is found.

Comment: But this wouldn't handle the error with invalid characters or the length being too long, right?

Comment: I have added 1 more check when attempt to change the worksheet name.