# excel vba add hyperlink to shape in group

Tags: vba, excel

I have absolutely no idea why i cannot add hyperlink to shape but only if its trigged by in-cell function. When I run it manually from immediate window, everything is working well. Also I don't have any troubles with doing it manually.

I have also no idea how write good error handling in vba

This is sample code.

```
function testCase(xlLabelName as String)
Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If shapeExist(sht, xlLabelName) Then
            sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sht.Shapes(xlLabelName), Address:="", SubAddress:="a1" 
            testCase = "Bingo"
        End If
    Next sht
End Function
```

From immediate window I get `Bingo` answer and in cell I get `#arg!` error and this is only line which is not executed.
I tried to ungroup shapes first using

```
Dim gshp As Shape
Dim shrng As ShapeRange
Dim tmp As String
Set gshp = sht.Shapes(getParentShape(xlLabelName))
tmp = gshp.Name
Set shrng = gshp.Ungroup
sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sht.Shapes(xlLabelName), Address:="", SubAddress:="a1"
shrng.Regroup
shrng.name = tmp
```

But it also failed. And still immediate window gives me correct answer (`bingo`)
All other operations are done as I needed (painting), only this one fails.
If I remove this problematic line I got correct response in cell.
The shape I'm trying to deal with is `msoFreeform`
The function to check if shape exist is just loop through all shapes in sheet and compare names (Lame but for now its working)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A UDF cannot add a hyperlink - at least not without convoluted workarounds. Why do you want to do it from a function rather than say an event?

Comment: You are my personal Jesus Christ. Now I know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would assign a macro to my shape so that it would run the following sub when clicked:

```
sub hyperlinkShape
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("C:\temp\test.xlsx")
End sub
```

If you're looking for a hyperlink within the workbook, such as changing sheets, you can write

```
sub hyperlinkShape
    Sheets("Desiredsheet").Select
End sub
```

This way the hyperlink would not be attached to the shape, but the sub. Clicking the shape can launch the sub.

For error handling, I suggest you read the answers from this thread I posted a few months back: [VBA Excel simple Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489035/vba-excel-simple-error-handling)