# Access VB: Validating blank values and incorrect values in a textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a textbox where the user inputs the ID of a row to be updated/edited. I got it to work properly when they enter an ID that exists, but I get an error when they input an ID that *doesn't* exist or when they leave it blank.

Goals:

1. Allow blank - if the user leaves the field blank, then I need to wipe the form and simply let the user continue (no message box needed).
2. Warn user when ID is not valid with a message box.

**Current Code**

```
Private Sub Text135_LostFocus()

    If Me.Text135 = Nothing Then

    MsgBox "Nothing entered into the ID field. Query will not run"

    GoTo Last_Line:

    Else

    sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Downtime WHERE ID = " & Forms![DTForm]![Text135] & ";"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

    Me.Text126.Value = rs!production_date
    Me.Text144.Value = rs!shift
    Me.Text116.Value = rs!job
    Me.Text118.Value = rs!suffix
    Me.Text121.Value = rs!reason
    Me.Text123.Value = rs!downtime_minutes
    Me.Text4.Value = rs!people_missing
    Me.Text128.Value = rs!comment
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

    Last_Line:

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel simple Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489035/vba-excel-simple-error-handling)

Comment: You may feel that this is not a duplicate question, however the standard response would be to include error handling, and also to check for the validity of a search term before executing the remainder of your code.

Comment: You could use `DCount` to check whether the ID exists.  If  `DCount("*","tbl_Downtime", "ID = " & Forms![DTForm]![Text135]) = 0`, then no matching ID is present.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Looking through your suggested answer now.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: IMO your duplicate question isn't really a duplicate in this specific case. I agree with your point about error handling, but apparently the OP **does** know about error handling - he's already trying to do it in his code in the question (`If Me.Text135 = Nothing Then ...`). He just doesn't know how to do it right in MS Access.

Comment: @ChristianSpecht The OP may understand error handling [and I don't mean to imply otherwise], but he is not using the VBA GoTo error handling method, which is somewhat unique and, in my opinion, counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: At least he doesn't use `On Error GoTo X`, but just `GoTo Last_Line:`, but it's not necessary in this example at all - and you're right, I always try to avoid it when I can just check beforehand if the field is empty. But as I understood it, the OP doesn't want to know about `On Error GoTo X`...he just wants to know the Access syntax to check two very specific things.

Answer (score 1):

1. Completely stop executing the sub when the field is blank:

   ```
   If Nz(Me.Text135) = "" Then 'Text135 is null or empty

       Exit Sub

   End If
   ```

   But if the code in your question is your actual code *(and not just a shortened example)*, you need neither the `Exit Sub` nor the `GoTo Last_Line:` part, because after the message box, the code execution will jump to the `End If` anyway.
2. Check whether the Recordset contains any rows:

   ```
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

   If rs.EOF Then

       'rs.EOF is True when there are no rows
       MsgBox "ID is not valid"

   Else

       'do stuff

   End If

   Set db = Nothing
   Set rs = Nothing
   ```

Comment: This seems to be ok, but I need it to stop executing the sub entirely if the field is blank. This is giving me an error because even though the field is blank, it keeps executing the rest of the sub.

Comment: Right, it definitely goes to `End If` if the field is blank. However, I placed the SQL statement and the rest of the code *underneath* that. So after it reaches the `End If`, it must go to the next section.