# Excel VBA On Error handling with User-Defined Type

Tags: vba, excel

this is an example sub to programatically install a type library for API. Why is the error handling routine failing? I attempted to follow the `try...except...finally` strategy I am familiar with from Python.

```
Sub CopyViewLayout():

'TRY:
On Error GoTo addReference
    Dim App As femap.model
    'COMPILE ERROR: USER TYPE NOT DEFINED

ResumeSub:
    Dim App As femap.model
    Set App = GetObject(, "femap.model")
    Dim rc As Variant
    Dim feView As femap.View
    Set feView = App.feView
    rc = feView.Get(0)

Exit Sub

'EXCEPT:
addReference:
    Dim vbaEditor As VBIDE.VBE
    Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim checkRef As VBIDE.Reference
    Dim filepath As String

    Set vbaEditor = Application.VBE
    Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    filepath = "C:\apps\FEMAPv11\"

    On Error GoTo Failure
    vbProj.References.AddFromFile (filepath & "femap.tlb")
    Set vbProj = Nothing
    Set vbaEditor = Nothing
    GoTo ResumeSub

'FINALLY
Failure:
    MsgBox ("couldn't find type library, exiting sub")

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I broke out this section from main because Error handling is just ridiculous in VBA... A better approach for me was to implement a **finite-state-machine** using Booleans.

**answer**

```
Sub refcheck()
Dim i As Long
Dim FEMAP_GUID As String
FEMAP_GUID = "{08F336B3-E668-11D4-9441-001083FFF11C}"
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.references
    For i = 1 To .Count
        If .Item(i).GUID = FEMAP_GUID Then
            Exit For
        Else
            'note: filepath is determined using Dir() elsewhere...
            .AddFromFile (filepath & "femap.tlb")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Error handling in VBA does not work anything like `try...catch` - trying to mimick it will only cause pain and suffering. [Handle runtime errors the way they're supposed to be](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30489275/1188513)

Comment: Error handling is probably the hardest challenge for me. To solve this, I drew a flowchart / route map of my dependencies and subs and created a set of module-scope booleans that act as "keys" into "gates", where gates are key-dependent calls in main.

Comment: Editing an answer into the question defeats the Q&A nature of Stack Overflow.. you should probably post an answer instead.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, OK, I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Error handling only handles runtime errors; not compile time errors. Use

```
Dim App as Object
```

And make sure you only `Dim App` once in your code.

By using `As Object`, you can late bind any object to it. You lose Intellisense while youre coding thought.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dick mentioned, use Late Binding but that alone is not enough. You will have to use it with proper Error Handling.

For example

```
Dim App As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set App = GetObject(, "femap.model")
On Error GoTo 0

If App Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please check if femap is installed"
    Exit Sub
End If

'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
```

If you are sure that it is installed then you are getting the error because the relevant library is not referenced. For that I would recommend having a look at [How to add a reference programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically)

I would however still suggest that you take the Late Binding route.