# How can I refer to another workbook by the content of a cell in the current workbook?

Tags: excel, variables, reference, vba

I'm making a macro in `excel 2010` and my goal is that everyone can use this macro for their own work. Therefore I have to make it very flexible.

Everyone names their own workbook (I've solved this in the macro by using ThisWorkbook), but everyone also names their own extraction file (from where the new data comes).

However, almost no-one knows how to work with VBA so it's not possible to adjust this reference in the code every time.

Therefore, I've added a new sheet: 'Personalize'

In here, the person can add the name of the extraction file in a specific cell.

Unfortunately **I don't know how to open a workbook that has the name of a specific cell in the current workbook.**

I tried, for example, `Windows("ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Personalize").Range("B3")").Activate` but it didn't work.

**The same thing with sheets that can be named differently, I don't know how to adjust them in the macro without using VBA in every case.**

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you so much in advance!

Kind Regards,

Hendrik

Comment: Are you trying to open a workbook or a worksheet?  Your code appears that you want to open a sheet but you keep saying workbook.

Comment: I try to open a workbook, but the name of that workbook changes. The user should be able to write the name of the other workbook in a certain cell of the current workbook. So the macro should think "I have to open the workbook with the same filename as the text in, for example, cell A3 of this workbook." I don't know if I'm being more clear with this explanation?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a workbook that's closed you need the full path:

```
dim wkb as workbook
dim wbPath as String

wbPath  = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Personalize").Range("B3").value
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath )
```

If you want to activate a workbook that's already opened, you don't need the full path but the workbook's name (such as "Workbook1.xlsx"). For this you can shave off the path before reaching "Workbook1.xlsx" (alternatively if the workbook is always going to be opened first, just have them enter the workbook's name directly and skip taking out the rest of the path):

```
dim wbname as String

wbname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Personalize").Range("B3").value
Do until Instr(wbname, "\") = 0
     wbname = Mid(wbname, instr(wbname, "\") + 1) 'I didn't test this, just going off the top of my head
Loop

Workbooks(wbName).Activate
```

Be sure to handle your errors properly. For reference: [VBA Excel simple Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489035/vba-excel-simple-error-handling)

Test what happens when you try to input a name that's incorrect, for example. You want to handle those errors with appropriate messageboxes or the users may feel like your program doesn't work.

Comment: The value in B3 would need to include the full path of the file, correct?

Comment: In the first case, yes. Since the workbook is closed, the code has to find where it is saved. in the second case, no, it's really the workbook's name. So you can have them put the path and use some string manipulation to shave everything off before `name.xlsm`. I can add that to my answer.

Comment: "In here, the person can add the name of the extraction file in a specific cell."  - I was just mentioning that because the mention of name and no path in the question, not sure if Hendrik knows that is required.

Comment: Thank you David, it works!! :) :) First, the whole macro kept repeating but I've deleted a part of your code and now everything works fine!

I now tried to do this for the sheets in ThisWorkbook as well, but those won't work. Any idea how to solve this?

'Specify data sheet name
                Dim datasheet As String
                datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Personalize").Range("B5").Value
                
Sheets("datasheet").Select

In any case: THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you means by doing this for the sheets in ThisWorkbook. You can just say `Thisworkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Activate` In the code you wrote in comment, unless the sheet's name is actually "sheetname" you should not write quotations. For example if `sheetname` contains "Sheet 1" then leave out the quotations or VBA will think you actually want to open the sheet called "sheetname" which doesn't exist. `Thisworkbook.Sheets(datasheet).Select`

Comment: I mean that the user should be able to change the name of the sheet, but the macro should still work properly. Is it more clear now?

Comment: What you need then is to use codenames for your sheets! Read on it here: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm Unfortunately, it doesn't work when referencing a different workbook, so you'd be stuck there... You'd have to include a hidden cell or something in the workbook , and then cycle through all sheets in the workbook by index looking for that hidden cell value. It's a bit more hacky, I will grant you that.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out now, thank you! :) it's in the workbook that's running the macro, so that shouldn't be an issue